# Money lodgement

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I sold my car 1st of February because my new company was providing us with free transportation (staff bus) so I really didn't have any use for it, though I used up all the car sale money in the same month of February and provided proof of car sale like, transaction receipt from the bank, change of ownership and receipt of payment from buyer. These are all photocopies because the car buyer held on to the originals, I applied for a UK tourist visa this month. Hope the car sale won't be an issue?

Comment: And also I changed job from company a, that I have been with since 2012 to company b in early February because the pay and position was much better, I was given a 3month probation which was completed early may so I was granted a short term leave which i want to use to travel to the UK. I applied this month, hoping to travel early July. Is this a problem?

Comment: What is your question, whether the car sale would be considered funds parking? No. Funds parking means there is unexplained income, and in your case the income is explained as you provided the documents.

Comment: Thanks George, what do you think about my second question concerning my job. Some say its too soon for me to go on a short term leave, that it will raise a red flag?

Comment: I don't see this question, but as a golden rule, anything you think might raise a red flag must be **proactively** and convincingly explained on your visa application. And if you can't think of a convincing explanation, this often means you should reevaluate your decision to apply for visa.

Comment: My question is, I was employed in February and applied for UK visa in may, hoping to travel in july. I was given a 3month probation at my office which I have completed, I want verify if it is too soon to go on a holiday? From UK visa point of view?