# Fiance visa UK, criteria for fiance visa UK, what is the process and information

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, nigerian-citizens, weddings

Please how much is a fiance visa to the UK, applying from Nigeria, and do I need to provide my bank statements or payslips??

Comment: Have you read [the description of how to apply?](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you want to get married in the U.K. but don’t intend to stay long-term, or whether you want to move to the UK permanently. You can find out more here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/nigeria The 6 month Marriage Visitor Visa costs £93 and you have to provide bank statements. The Family of Settled Person Visa costs £1,523, there are various criteria including an income threshold of £18,600 (if no children involved).

Comment: Thank you, one last question. Do I need to provide my bank statements for Family of Settled Person visa? And can this be appealed if one is refused? Will that be free? And lastly how much will it cost to change to marriage visa after getting married in the UK.

Comment: @Aquaman If you enter on a Marriage Visitor Visa you can’t change to another visa type while you’re in the UK, you have to leave and apply again. You need to follow the links on the UK Gov page and read the information provided to understand the documentation required for each type of visa.

Comment: @Aquaman Was your Visit Visa application approved https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115711/money-lodgement? If not, applying for a marriage visa is very likely to be refused as it will look like you are just using it to try to get into the UK

Comment: Yes, it was approved and i have returned back to Nigeria from UK. I met all her friends and family and we lived together during my stay. I proposed to her in the UK and she said yes, so I'm back in Nigeria and I want to apply for a visa to join her. I don't want to apply for a marriage visit visa, I want to apply for a Family of Settled Person visa, that's why I want to know if I would've to provide my bank statement or not? And can this visa be appealed in case of a refusal? Please your assistance will be appreciated

Comment: @Aquaman My understanding is that for a settlement visa it is the finances of the U.K. sponsor that matter, there are strict criteria on income levels. There is a good overview of appeals here https://iasservices.org.uk/successfully-appealing-spouse-visa-refused/ they are not free but the cost is not prohibitive